# Creating a custom Word Add-In/VSTO

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, vsto

I am attempting to create a Word add-in for Office 2010.  I have used Visual Basic in the past but moved on to PowerShell for most of my scripting now.

However, when I'm in Visual Studio creating a new Add-In, I have to use Visual Basic (or C++ but i'm a lot more familiar with VB) and i'm running into problems.

The main problem being, I've never done this before and i've never been asked to do this so I've never looked into how it works.

So far, I've created the project and the ribbon icons.  I have 2 icons.  One is meant to print the name of the current active file into the document (at the end of the document no matter where I'm at IN the document) and the other is meant to print the path to the active document wherever my cursor is inside the document.

So...I don't expect anyone to write my code for me but, if someone could point me in the direction of a quick "How-To" for these items, i'd appreciate it!

Comment: I'm afraid asking for samples, books, tutorials, etc. is off-topic. What you need is to familiarize yourself with the Word and Office object models, which is usually more easily done in the VBA environment. You'll also find a lot more code samples and discussions for Word VBA. Word VBA will "translate" fairly simply to VB.NET (as opposed to C# - I assume you mean C# in your question and not C++ as there is no VSTO for C++...) If you search things like Path and FileName in the object model (I recommend F2 - the object browser) you should find those. And record a macro for inserting into a doc.

Comment: When you have those basics, give it a try and then you can come back with the bit of code you have and ask a more specific question, such as: How do I change this code to insert at the end of a document.

Comment: I completely understand.  So far, i've come up with this..

`Private Sub btnFilename_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btnFilename.Click

        Dim docName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
        MsgBox(docName.Name)
End Sub1`

And that will pop up a messagebox with the information i'm looking for.  I'm not stuck at, instead of a messagebox, getting it to print at the end of the actual document.

I found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx which seems to be close but not quite

Comment: Ok, another update.  I have the text going into the document with the "content.insertafter" option.  It's working perfectly.

I guess my last question to this is, how would I insert at the cursor?  One of the items needs to insert at the end, one needs to insert where the user has clicked.

I tried "insertbefore" and it goes to the beginning of the document.  I'm still looking but, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Last update.  Google-Fu came through.  Looks like I have it working as I want it.  In case anyone stumbles onto this thread looking for the same thing, here's what I did.

`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertAfter(Text:="The Text")`

Thanks for helping me think through this!

Comment: @Chris you can update your question instead of adding comments. Also you're allowed to answer your own question if you found what you looked for so others may use this information.

Answer (score 0):

Last update. Google-Fu came through. Looks like I have it working as I want it. In case anyone stumbles onto this thread looking for the same thing, here's what I did.

To insert at the end of a document:

```
Dim docName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter(Text:=vbCrLf & docName.Name)
```

To insert at the cursor

```
    Dim docName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertAfter(Text:=docName.Path)
```

Thanks for helping me think through this!

Comment: Glad you were able to track it down :-) One thing about your code: You declare and instantiate `docName`, but then you don't use it. Your second line of the first code snippet should start `docName.Content.InsertAfter`

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean.  Thanks a lot!  Side note/question..  I've been trying to modify the font of the text it inserts but it ends up changing the font to the entire document instead.

I'm trying 

'docname.range.font.size = "20"

Comment: docName.Range (or docname.content) return the *entire document*. If you want to format only a small part you need to declare a Range object, "collapse" it, then insert the content and format. There are lots of code samples "out there" that do that... Not possible, really, to post the entirety in a comment.